# Show that a determinant involving modified Chebyshev polynomials is zero

Tags: recurrence-relations, determinant

Let $(P_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be modified Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind, defined by (choose your preferred definition, they are equivalent):

- they satisfy
  $$
  \left \{
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  P_0 & = & 0 \\
  P_1 & = & 1 \\
  \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, P_{n-1} + P_{n+1} & = & XP_n
  \end{array}
  \right.
  $$
- they satisfy
  $$ P_n(2\cos \theta) = \frac{\sin n\theta}{\sin \theta} $$

Now, define bivariate polynomials in $t$ and $u$ :
$$ p[n] := P_n(t + u) $$
$$ a[n] := tp[n] - p[n-1]$$

**The question is**: how can one show elegantly, concisely that for any $(m, n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$,

$$
\bbox[white, 10px, border: 3px solid red]{
\left |
\begin{array}{ccc}
p[m]+p[n] & a[m] + a[n] \\
p[m + n] & 1 + a[m + n] \\
\end{array}
\right | = 0
}
$$ ?

I have a very inelegant proof. Here it is. Too long, too much trigonometry.
$$ \frac{p[m] + p[n]}{a[m] + a[n]} - \frac{p[m + n]}{1 + a[m + n]} = \frac{(p[m] + p[n])(1 + a[m + n]) - (p[m + n])(a[m] + a[n])}{(a[m] + a[n])(1 + a[m + n])} $$
Suppose the denominator not zero, consider the numerator,
$$ E := (p[m] + p[n])(1 + a[m + n]) - (p[m + n])(a[m] + a[n]) $$
Since $ a[n] = t p[n] - p[n - 1] $,
$$ E = (p[m] + p[n])(1 + tp[m + n] - p[m + n - 1]) - (p[m + n])(t p[m] - p[m - 1] + t p[n] - p[n - 1])$$
The terms that contain $ t $ vanish. Remains:
$$ E = (p[m] + p[n])(1 - p[m + n - 1]) + (p[m + n])(p[m - 1] + p[n - 1]) $$

Since $ p[n] = P_n(t + u) = \frac{\sin n\theta}{\sin \theta} $ with the change of variable $ t + u = 2 \cos \theta $, one has:

$$ E = \left(\frac{\sin m\theta}{\sin \theta} + \frac{\sin n\theta}{\sin \theta} \right)\left(1 - \frac{\sin (m+n-1)\theta}{\sin \theta}\right) + \left(\frac{\sin (m+n)\theta}{\sin \theta}\right)\left(\frac{\sin (m-1)\theta}{\sin \theta} + \frac{\sin (n-1)\theta}{\sin \theta}\right) $$

$$ ( \sin^2 \theta ) E = \bbox[pink, 3px]{(\sin m\theta + \sin n\theta )}\bbox[lightgreen, 3px]{(\sin \theta - \sin (m+n-1)\theta)} + (\sin (m+n)\theta)\bbox[pink, 3px]{(\sin (m-1)\theta + \sin (n-1)\theta)} $$

By applying the following trigonometric identities:

$$\bbox[pink, 3px]{ \sin p + \sin q = 2 \sin \left ( \frac{p+q}{2} \right ) \cos \left ( \frac{p-q}{2} \right ) }
, 
\bbox[lightgreen, 3px]{ \sin p - \sin q = 2 \cos \left ( \frac{p+q}{2} \right ) \sin \left ( \frac{p-q}{2} \right ) }
$$
We get

$$( \sin^2 \theta ) E =
     \bbox[pink, 3px]{ 2 \sin \left ( \frac{(m+n)\theta}{2} \right )\cos \left ( \frac{(m-n)\theta}{2} \right )}
     \bbox[lightgreen, 3px]{ 2 \cos \left ( \frac{(m+n)\theta}{2} \right )\sin \left ( \frac{(2-m-n)\theta}{2} \right )}
     +
     (\sin (m+n)\theta)
     \bbox[pink, 3px]{ 2 \sin \left ( \frac{(m+n-2)\theta}{2} \right )\cos \left ( \frac{(m-n)\theta}{2} \right )}
$$

Finally, by applying

$$ 2 \sin \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) \cos \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) = \sin\left(x\right) $$

one notices that everything vanishes, and so:

$$ ( \sin^2 \theta ) E = 0 $$

We now suppose $ \sin \theta \neq 0 $ and arrive at:

$$ E = 0 $$

$$ \frac{p[m] + p[n]}{a[m] + a[n]} - \frac{p[m + n]}{1 + a[m + n]} = 0 $$

... which can be transformed to the desired result.

But we've left behind so many assumptions

- $ a[m] + a[n] \neq 0 $
- $1 +  a[m + n] \neq 0 $
- $ t + u $ can be written $ 2 \cos \theta $
- $ \theta \notin 2 \pi \mathbb{Z} $

... that this proof leaves a bad taste.

**Reformulated, the question is:** I'm sure we can do better, I have the feeling that a simple induction on $m+n$ should succeed, but I can't get at it. Can someone show me?